# how to get the list populated from the return command?

Tags: apex, variable-scope

Hey Guys and thanks for all the help.
my problem is how to get the "Animals" from the return command my code is as follows

```
    public class AnimalLocator {

    public static List <String>getAnimals(){
        Http http           = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals/');
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);        

        if(response.getStatusCode()==200){
        Map<String,Object> results = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
        List<object> animals  = (List<Object>) results.get('animals'); 

        }
        return animals;
    }
}
```

and i get the error:

Variable does not exist: animals – in line 15

can you help me see what's my problem is?
any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You declared your variable `animals` inside a conditional block and thus it is only accessible within that block.

Change to this and you should be good:

```
List<object> animals = New List<object>();

if(response.getStatusCode()==200){
        Map<String,Object> results = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
          = (List<Object>) results.get('animals'); 

        }
        return animals;
```

Comment: ill check it out and let you know tyvm

Answer (score 1):

Apex has block scope. The variable you declare in a block are visible only inside the block after their their declaration. In your case, you can return the list from inside your block if the request is successful else return and empty list.

The list that you are recieving from your end point is

`{"animals":["majestic badger","fluffy bunny","scary bear","chicken"]}`

```
public class AnimalLocator {

 public static List <String> getAnimals() {
  Http http = new Http();
  HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
  request.setEndpoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals/');
  request.setMethod('GET');
  HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

  if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
   Map < String, Object > results = (Map < String, Object > ) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
   List <String> animals = (List <String> ) results.get('animals');
   return animals;
  } else {
   return new List < String> ();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: ok ill check it out and let you know